Irrigation installation in the yard
I just had irrigation installed with sprinklers.
I am concerned that some of the sprinklers are about 6 feet away from the trunk of main trees that need major irrigation. ( called oriental arborvitae Platycladus ) . I have already lost couple of them due to dehydration.
Is that distance ok?

I usually think of sprinklers for lawns, flower beds, etc. But trees typically (at least in my area) have deep roots that can get plenty of water from the soil.

Does the water hit the trunk of the trees?

Tree roots cover (at least, usually more than) the entire width of the branches - watering "right at the trunk" is not particularly better than watering that whole area.

Well my trees are drying out and no the water does not hit the trunk

Distance is not as important as volume of water.  Your trees may be dying because of something other than lack of water.  Far more info is needed here.

There was a year that it reached 101 degrees in the summer and we had 4 months of no rain in the pacific north west. That year, I did not water my yard at all and I lost two threes and three shrubs.

How do you know that you lost them due to dehydration and not something else?  And if you do know it, why didn't you water them by hand?

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Gardening Site

Why did I not water when it was 101? Because I am a doctor and was working out of state during the pandemic at that time so did not think of my garden much

Apologies! I didn't mean for you to justify yourself, only to understand the expectation.  Now we can say you are in an area subject to heat waves and you leave your garden unattended for long periods.  Maybe when you installed it neither of those had ever happened, maybe they don't anymore.   It's easy to design for such conditions but an ordinary home sprinkler system would not include that need.

You should include all the additional information in the question, and move it to the Gardening SE with the Irrigation tag.  Knowing the specific trees and the conditions you want to handle, you could bring back the installer to add a zone for them.


Six feet, or any distance, is not necessarily "too far" for a sprinkler.  It depends on the sprinkler's throw.   Usually sprinklers are designed to overlap significantly.  A rule of thumb I have seen is that each sprinkler should spray as far as its adjacent ones.   If they do, it makes no difference how far apart they are.  Your question should be: How was the system designed, was that design appropriate for your plants, and was it implemented as designed?
Trees are not normally irrigated by sprinklers.  Drip hoses are more normal.  And depending on where you are, mature trees may not need irrigation.  Again, you need to look at the design and determine how, and if, it was meant to irrigate your trees.


To expand on point two - sprinklers are great for watering things near the surface, but to provide significant water at the depth that a big tree requires, you are likely to need to saturate the surface far more than is good for it. In extreme conditions, you should consider placing a vertical pipe and filling it directly, so that the water goes deep enough.

Tree roots generally extend about as far as the canopy covers, so any water thrown somewhere under the tree has good odds of being picked up by the tree

Please note, it's not my intention to instruct OP or anyone on how to water their particular trees.   Only to say a typical vanilla residential sprinkler system does not include significant formal design, it just follows installer rules of thumb to do a good enough job on lawns and flower beds.
